# How to pull a file from client to FTP server?

Tags: java

I want to pull a file from client to ftp server.the code must be run in the ftp server pc not in the client side.Its not about upload a file from client side.How to do it in java?

Comment: Searching for "java ftp" yields what sort of answers? Surely more than what you've got here. Questions without any demonstrated effort to solve the problem are considered off-topic.

Comment: "Pulling" a file from a client to a server would mean there would have to be a process on the "client" listening for a connection from the "server", which would mean the "client" is the server and the "server" is the client.  Or do you mean that after the client connects to the FTP server via the FTP protocol, the server take some acton to cause the client to send a file?  That is not within the capability of the FTP protocol.

Comment: I have searched for "java ftp" .what I got is client uploads file in the ftp server and the code runs in the client pc. But i need to do it in the server side.FTP server will pull files from the client pc.

Comment: Have you investigated scp or rsync over SSH?  That may be more what you are looking for.

Comment: In scp or rsync over SSH ,ftp server copies the file from server to the client pc.But I need to access the client from ftp server and upload a file in the ftp server by running the code in the ftp server pc. Basically What I have said earlier FTP server pulls the file from client.

Comment: If I understand you, the sequence of events is that the client initiates an FTP session to the server and then the server tells the client what file to send.  This is not possible using standard FTP protocol.  You would have to modify the FTP server _and_ the client to support this.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, here's a possible solution.

Write a simple socket server, let's call it `SendFTP` that runs on the client, and a simple socket client (call this `RequestFTP`) that runs on the server.

The server executes `RequestFTP`, which connects to `SendFTP` running on the client.  You would design your own protocol for this, via which `RequestFTP` tells `SendFTP` which file(s) to send.

`SendFTP` then initiates an FTP session (from the client) with the server and sends the requested files.

Comment: Thanks! But I have done this already.Similar to your solution I have requested a file from the server then client sends it.But it is not what i want.after the client server connection establishment server automatically pulls the file from a client pc directory,this is what i want.

Comment: I keep telling you this is NOT POSSIBLE with the existing FTP protocol.

Comment: Thanks Jim for your information.After searching for the last 1 week i think this is actually not possible.Can you kindly tell me with which protocol I can do this in JAVA?